# Meta key:value fields returning NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which revolves around meta_key and meta_value fields in a database. It's almost there but when I added INNER JOIN wp_enrolments, 'class' and 'fee-types' are now returning NULL. It's like it conflicts with INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta line.

The structure of the wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta is

- id
- meta_key
- meta_value

The structure of the wp_enrolments table is:

- id
- firstname
- surname
- etc

I'd appreciate if you could take a look at my syntax and spot any errors.

```
SELECT 
  O.order_item_id, O.order_item_name,
  E.firstname,
  MAX(CASE WHEN OIM.meta_key = 'class' THEN OIM.meta_value END) AS 'class',
  MAX(CASE WHEN OIM.meta_key = 'fee-type' THEN OIM.meta_value END) AS 'fees'
FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items O
INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta OIM ON O.order_item_id = OIM.order_item_id
INNER JOIN wp_enrolments E ON E.id = OIM.meta_value AND OIM.meta_key = 'enrolment_id'
GROUP BY O.order_item_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need a `LEFT JOIN`.  Also, fix the `GROUP BY` to match the `SELECT`, and don't use single quotes for column aliases:

```
SELECT O.order_item_id, O.order_item_name, E.firstname,
       MAX(CASE WHEN OIM.meta_key = 'class' THEN OIM.meta_value END) AS class,
       MAX(CASE WHEN OIM.meta_key = 'fee-type' THEN OIM.meta_value END) AS fees
FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items O JOIN
     wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta OIM
     ON O.order_item_id = OIM.order_item_id LEFT JOIN
     wp_enrolments E
     ON E.id = OIM.meta_value AND
        OIM.meta_key = 'enrolment_id'
GROUP BY O.order_item_id, O.order_item_name, E.firstname;
```

Comment: So the output of that query is two rows which should be part of the same row i.e for the first row 'firstname' is NULL and for the second row 'class' and 'fee-type' are NULL :)

Comment: I suspect that removing `O.order_item_id` and  `O.order_item_name` from the `GROUP BY` and the `SELECT` will solve your issue.  However, your question doesn't have enough information for me to know if this is really the case.